# ngModel not registering input value in Angular 16

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel

So I am working on this code which uses Angular 16.
For some reason when I submit the form which is supposed to console log the `info` object, the values inside the object remain empty which also causes my POST request to fail. What could the cause be?

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
@Component({
  selector: 'new-prof-dialog',
  templateUrl: 'new-prof.dialog.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-album.dialog.scss']
})

export class NewProfDialog implements OnInit {
  info= {
    name: '',
    year: 1900,
    profession: '',
  };

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit(): void { }

  createNewAccount(info: any) {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      })
    };
    this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:3000/info/create', JSON.stringify(info), httpOptions).subscribe();
  }

}
```

and here is a few lines from the html:

```
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Year</mat-label>
    <input matInput name="year" [(ngModel)]="info.year" type="text">
  </mat-form-field>
    <button class="confirm-button" mat-raised-button mat-dialog-close (click)="createNewAccount(info)">Confirm</button>
```

I can't seem to find the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure if `ngModel` binding works with nested object properties like that. You could try a getter/setter pair (`get infoYear(): number { return this.info.year; }` and `set infoYear(value: number): void { this.info.year = value; }`) then binding to them (`<input [(ngModel)]="infoYear"/>`) but I would strongly recommend you look at [Reactive Forms](https://angular.dev/guide/forms/reactive-forms) instead. They're much better at managing complex form models including nested objects/arrays/dynamic collections/etc...

Comment: Also a little unsure of why you're passing `info` to `createNewAccount()`. It's already available on the class via `this.info`.

Comment: @tevpev123 could you replicate the issue in a stackblitz and update the same on the question!

Answer (score 0):

remove JSON.stringify(info) and just put info.

```
this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/info/create', info, httpOptions).subscribe();
```